# HTML 5 Geolocation not working in IE 10 in Windows 8

Tags: html, geolocation

HTML 5 geolocation not working in IE 10 in Windows 8 machine.

But the same is working fine in Chrome using the **same internet package** as IE.

Example: On browsing the following site, getting "Error: Geolocation Service Failed" in IE. But working fine in Chrome.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Another point to note is, it is working fine in IE 10 of Windows 7 machine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Was a proxy involved?